# Http post request not being noticed on MVC ASP.NET Deployment

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7, post, get

I have two an action method
 - > RoleURLManagement

which differs with its input parameter in the get compared to the post so we have

```
     [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
     public ActionResult RoleURLManagement(string id)
     {
     }
```

and

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult RoleURLManagement(aspnet_Roles rt)
    {
    }
```

The get is bringing back a page based on the id in the URL.
The Post should be updating that record.

Now,

this works perfect locally on my machine, 
But I have deployed it, It does not recognise the Post at all.

Not sure why this is happening, on the view I have a BeginForm posting to this method.

Wow

HTML

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("RoleURLManagement", "Role", FormMethod.Post))
    {%>

 <fieldset>
  <%--  <legend>Fields</legend>--%>

    <div class="display-label">ApplicationId</div>
    <div class="display-field"><%: Model.ApplicationId%></div>
    <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ApplicationId, new {@class   = "RemoveAttribute" })%>

    <div class="display-label">RoleId</div>
    <div class="display-field"><%: Model.RoleId%></div>
    <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RoleId, new {@class = "RemoveAttribute" })%>

    <div class="display-label">RoleName</div>
    <h1><div class="display-field"><%: Model.RoleName%></div></h1>
  <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.RoleName, new {@class = "RemoveAttribute" })%>
    <%: Html.TextBox("RoleName") %>


    <div class="display-label">LoweredRoleName</div>
    <div class="display-field"><%: Model.LoweredRoleName%></div>
    <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LoweredRoleName, new {@class = "RemoveAttribute" })%>

    <div class="display-label">Description</div>
    <div class="display-field"><%: Model.Description%></div>
    <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Description, new {@class = "RemoveAttribute" })%>

</fieldset>


 <div class="siteCheck"> 
 <%=Html.SiteMapCheckBoxManagement("checkManagememt", Model)%>
 <%=Html.TextArea("t")%>
 </div>

 <input type="submit" value="Map Sites to Role" />

 <% } %>
```

Comment: I have  Request.Form["t"]; in my post method not sure if that makes a difference with anything?

Comment: basically its not distinguishing get and post i thinks

Comment: Can you post the markup?

Comment: Are you using IIS on both your local machine and on the server? Are they the same version? (e.g. IIS 6 vs IIS 7)

Comment: I'm not using iis on my local machine, just the server

Comment: I would suggest you start by testing with IIS on your local box so that you can reproduce the problem. IIS and the VS Development Server handle HTTP requests different.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... not sure why that isn't work... here are a few stabs at ideas:

1) You aren't passing the id into the post method?

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult RoleURLManagement(string id)
{
}

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult RoleURLManagement(string id, aspnet_Roles rt)
{
}
```

2) See if it works when accepting a FormCollection instead of aspnet_Roles: (then get the role based on ID, and do an UpdateModel(role) to apply the changes)

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public ActionResult RoleURLManagement(string id)
{
}

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult RoleURLManagement(string id, FormCollection form)
{
}
```

Of course neither of those explain why it works different on your machine than the server. Do you have different versions of IIS? RC of MVC 2?

Good Luck...

Comment: Hmm seems like it still isnt distingushing the Action Names on the webserver